# Dynamic filtered values in vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Here's part of my vuex code:

```
//companiesStore.js
const state = {
    all: [],
    one: defaultItem,
    filtered: [],
    'loading': {
        'all': false,
        'one': false,
        'filtered': false,
    },
};
```

the problem is that I need filtered values in a couple of different components and they need to be filtered differently, also they need to be loaded dynamically.

I heard there might be problem with dynamically building array of arrays of objects in Vuex. Is it true? How should I approach this?

Comment: You could create Vuex getters that return your filtered values.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that i want to load only couple dozens of each item out of 100 000+, hence I'm not keeping all the data in store all the time